# Is there something wrong with my switch statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The function `handleForm` is triggered when the button is clicked, and it is supose to check all the inputs.

```js
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState({
    lastName: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastNameHiragana: "",
    firstNameHiragana: "",
    birthday: "",
    sex: "",
    telephone: "",
    email: "",
    joinedDate: "",
    division: "",
  });

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    lastName: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastNameHiragana: "",
    firstNameHiragana: "",
    birthday: "",
    sex: "",
    telephone: "",
    email: "",
    joinedDate: "",
    division: "",
  });


function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (const name in values) {
      const hiraganaRegex = /^[ぁ-ん]+$/;
      switch (name) {
        case "lastName":
          if (!values[name]) {
            setErrorMessage({ ...errorMessage, lastName: "必須項目です" });
          }
          break;

        case "firstName":
          if (!values[name]) {
            setErrorMessage({ ...errorMessage, firstName: "必須項目です" });
          } else {
            setErrorMessage({ ...errorMessage, firstName: "" });
          }
          break;

        case "lastNameHiragana":
          if (!hiraganaRegex.test(values[name]) && values[name]) {
            setErrorMessage({
              ...errorMessage,
              lastNameHiragana: "ひらがなで入力して下さい。",
            });
          }
          break;

        case "firstNameHiragana":
          if (!hiraganaRegex.test(values[name]) && values[name]) {
            setErrorMessage({
              ...errorMessage,
              firstNameHiragana: "ひらがなで入力して下さい。",
            });
          }
          break;

        case "birthday":
          if (values[name]) {
            setErrorMessage({ ...errorMessage, birthday: "" });
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

When I test this, the `setErrorMessage` of the first case does not trigger. I check the state in the dev tools, and it does not update.
It only updates the second case.
I inserted a `console.log` in the first case (inside the `if` statement), and it logs, proving that it is getting there. But somehow it is not updating the `errorMessage`.

Is there something wrong in my code (syntax, etc.)?
Somebody knows what is wrong here?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're going to being storing state data in an object, you should look into `useReducer` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop you are overwriting the entire `errorMessage` object. Instead of updating just that specific error message for just that input being checked.

You could update each error message separately using the `input name` as the `key` :

```js
function handleForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newErrorMessage = {};

  for (const name in values) {
    const hiraganaRegex = /^[ぁ-ん]+$/;
    switch (name) {
      case "lastName":
        if (!values[name]) {
          newErrorMessage[name] = "必須項目です";
        }
        break;

      case "firstName":
        if (!values[name]) {
          newErrorMessage[name] = "必須項目です";
        } else {
          newErrorMessage[name] = "";
        }
        break;

      case "lastNameHiragana":
        if (!hiraganaRegex.test(values[name]) && values[name]) {
          newErrorMessage[name] = "ひらがなで入力して下さい。";
        }
        break;

      case "firstNameHiragana":
        if (!hiraganaRegex.test(values[name]) && values[name]) {
          newErrorMessage[name] = "ひらがなで入力して下さい。";
        }
        break;

      case "birthday":
        if (values[name]) {
          newErrorMessage[name] = "";
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  setErrorMessage(newErrorMessage);
}
```

By using the `newErrorMessage` it will update each error message inside the loop. After the loop is finished, we call `setErrorMessage`  with the `newErrorMessage` object, which will update the error messages in the state.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!
Just a question tho (forgive my ignorance):
>You could update each error message separately using the input name as the key
Could you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not updating the `errorMessage` state correctly in the first case of your switch statement. Instead of spreading the current `errorMessage` state, you are overwriting it with the new value.

This may fix that:

```
case "lastName":
  if (!values[name]) {
    setErrorMessage((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, lastName: "必須項目です" }));
  } else {
    setErrorMessage((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, lastName: "" }));
  }
  break;
```